# how to get country code like(+91 ,+1 etc) using user's current location flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, locale, mobile-application, mobile-country-code

I'm working on flutter app and I have a text widget where I want to show user's current country code based on his location without any dropdown.
I'm getting value like "IN","US" using Locale, but I don't want it,
I need numeric country code like +91 (for India), +1 (for US) etc.
anyone help me please.

Answer (score 7):

You can use these files [countries.dart](https://github.com/figengungor/country_pickers/blob/master/lib/countries.dart) and [country.dart](https://github.com/figengungor/country_pickers/blob/master/lib/country.dart)
Get the user country code from `http://ip-api.com/json` with [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package and then use it to get the country phone code from `countryList`:

```
 Future<String> getCountryPhoneCode() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://ip-api.com/json'));
    var jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    final isoCode = jsonResponse['countryCode'];
    print("country code " + isoCode);
    return "+" +
        countryList
            .firstWhere((element) => element.isoCode == isoCode,
                orElse: () => countryList.first)
            .phoneCode;
  }
```

**I tested this and it works for me but you can improve it to avoid http exceptions**

Comment: it return me iso code "IN"  but for same device flutter Locale return "US",
how it is possible ?

Comment: This is not the expected behavior, try to use it with FutureBuilder, it should show the country phone code , it's just that I print the isoCode to make sure the API works fine or like this ```final phoneCode=await getCountryPhoneCode();```

Comment: Concerning the flutter locale, it returns the language code of that device, not the country code, while this function gets the country code based on your IP address

Answer (score 0):

You can use [country_codes](https://pub.dev/packages/country_codes) package:

Install:

```
dependencies:
  country_codes: ^2.0.1
```

Usage:

```
await CountryCodes.init(); // Optionally, you may provide a `Locale` to get countrie's localizadName

final CountryDetails details = CountryCodes.detailsForLocale();
print(details.alpha2Code); // Displays alpha2Code, for example US.
print(details.dialCode); // Displays the dial code, for example +1.
print(details.name); // Displays the extended name, for example United States.
print(details.localizedName);
```

Comment: it wont work on web..
i need for app and web both

Answer (score 0):

If you have any country code and wants to get corresponding country name, use [country_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/country_picker) package like this

```
Country.tryParse(countryCode)?.name; // for name in english
Country.tryParse(countryCode)?.phoneCode; // for phone code
```